# Nested Rails 4 Form Accessing Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested form that has 3 fields repeated 7 times. I want to do a check that if the first field group is empty, then it will stop the process and return an error asking a user to fill in those fields.

I already have a check in that it will drop any empty field groups from the Create action in the controller, that is the "reject_if: => :all_blank" part of the model. However, it deletes the first entry, which I would instead rather run a check on. This code doesn't work, and I don't know where to go from here besides trying to refine the check_attendee_form method. Any help would be appreciated out there.

Here are the related Models:

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base

# Database Relationships
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
has_many :attendees

# Form relationships
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendees,
            :allow_destroy => true,
            :reject_if => :all_blank

class Attendee < ActiveRecord::Base

# Database relationships
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user

delegate :event, :event_id, to: :registration

# Validations
validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
```

Controller Create and New Actions and Methods

```
def new
@registration = @event.registrations.new
7.times { @registration.attendees.build }
end

def create
 @registration = @event.registrations.new(registration_params)
 @registration.user = current_user
 check_attendee_form

respond_to do |format|
  if @registration.save
    format.html { redirect_to event_path(@event), notice: 'You are now registered.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @registration }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @registration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def check_registration
@check = Registration.find_by event_id: @event, user_id: current_user
if @check.nil?
 @registration = @event.registrations.new
 @registration.user = current_user
else
 redirect_to event_path(@event),
             notice: "You're already registered!"
end
end

def check_attendee_form

  @attendees_check = @registration.find_by(attendees_attributes: params[:first_name])

  if @attendees_check.first.nil?
  render :new, notice: "You need to put in your name at least!"
  else
  end
end
```

And finally, the essential form info:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@event, @registration], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

<%= render 'shared/errors', object: @registration %>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :attendees, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } }  do |a| %>

<div>

<%= a.label :first_name %>:
<%= a.text_field :first_name %>
<%= error_span([:first_name]) %>
<%= a.label :last_name %>:
<%= a.text_field :last_name %>
<%= error_span([:last_name]) %>
<%= a.label :fundraising_goal %>:
<%= a.number_field :fundraising_goal, placeholder: 'No Commas' %>
<%= error_span([:fundraising_goal]) %>
```

Here are the params that are getting submitted:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"dNR5QCBFplsAG0wzy87+hzaKuG6h2Mlb6xpmKEM0Kko=",
"registration"=>{"attendees_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>"",
"last_name"=>"",
"fundraising_goal"=>""},
"1"=>{"first_name"=>"",
"last_name"=>"",
"fundraising_goal"=>""},
"2"=>{"first_name"=>"",
"last_name"=>"",
"fundraising_goal"=>""},
"3"=>{"first_name"=>"",
"last_name"=>"",
"fundraising_goal"=>""},
"4"=>{"first_name"=>"",
"last_name"=>"",
"fundraising_goal"=>""},
"5"=>{"first_name"=>"",
"last_name"=>"",
"fundraising_goal"=>""},
"6"=>{"first_name"=>"",
"last_name"=>"",
"fundraising_goal"=>""}}},
"commit"=>"Create Registration",
"event_id"=>"5"}
```

How do I access the first array object with attendees_attributes of ID [0] in this form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure that at least one Attendee is entered for a registration, I believe you could drop the `check_attendee_form` method and add the following validation to registration.rb:

```
validate :check_minimum_attendees

def check_minimum_attendees
    errors.add(:attendees, 'must be entered') if attendees.size == 0
end
```

Comment: This does the job, but then creates another problem which is that on throwing an error, it doesn't recreate the :new action on the controller. Any idea how to get that to happen?

Comment: Right - the attendees have been removed because of being empty.  There's probably a better way to do this, but you could add the `7.times { @registration.attendees.build }` line to the `else` portion of your create method.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. However, I'd upvote our comment for at least getting me moving in a good direction but I don't have enough rep points to do so.

Comment: I put this in and it worked. `def check_minimum_attendees
  if attendees.size == 0
    errors.add_on_blank(:attendees)
    7.times { attendees.build } 
  else
end
end`

Answer (score 0):

Your form attributes is nested hash, you can access attendees using id like 0, 1 etc

i.e params[registration][attendees][0]

Comment: I don't understand how that would look in the code.

Comment: Hi , he want to access first array of element in hash. If you want access 1st element array in your controller action then parameter come like params[registration][attendees][0]  ,it will return  like             {"first_name"=>"",
"last_name"=>"",
"fundraising_goal"=>""}

Comment: params[registration][attendees][0] using , we can get first array element

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, the problem is with :reject_if condition.
You can use a Proc (or lambda) to 'reject' any unsuitable nested attributes.

```
:reject_if => lambda { |e| e[:last_name].blank? && (e[:_destroy].blank? || e[:_destroy] == 'false') }
```

Use validation as @keyzee suggested:

```
validate :check_attendees

def check_attendees
  errors.add(:attendees, 'must be entered') unless attendees.count
  attendees.each do |a|
    errors.add(:attendees, 'error message here') if condition_here
  end
end
```

Or create custom validator in lib folder (lib/check_attendees_validator.rb):

```
class CheckAttendeesValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << 'error_message' if condition_here
  end
end
```

And then use it in a model:

```
validates :attendees, check_attendees: true
```

Comment: And use validation as @keyzee suggested

Comment: Neither of these worked. It seems like your code is the most elegant, but it doesn't do what I think I'm trying to do.  If I add the "check attendees" to the Registration model (or attendee), and set the "condition_here" to attendee.size == 0, it just skips over the validation. Any ideas?

Comment: If you set 'reject_if' - it will be run before validation. In my example it removes all nested records in case if 'last_name' field is blank and '_destroy' is not set to 'true'. 'attendees.each' block allows you to validate each nested record using block variable ('a' in this example). errors.add(:attendees, 'last name can't be empty') if a.last_name.blank?